# Update existing app in Enterprise App Store

Tags: wso2, wso2-es

I am running WSO2 EMM v1.1.0. I have an existing android app in my Enterprise store. I wanted to update the app to see if the devices that have version 1 will be notified that a new version is available or if the new version would be automatically downloaded and installed.  I clicked on the existing app in the /publisher/assets/mobileapp/ page but I did not see a update or replace option.  I tried to use the New Application button but when I tried to submit the new version 2 of the app I got an error that version 1 already exists. I tried to retire version 1 of the app and then use the New Application button but again I got the version 1 already exist error.  What is the process for updating an app beyond version 1? Does a push app update feature exist in wso2?

Answer (score 1):

EMM 1.1.0 does not support app update out of the box. What you can do is create a new version of the app with same name and different mobile app binary version and retire the old one. Please also make sure to upload an app which has different binary version when creating a new app. App update will be supported in future version of EMM.